# Facebook C# SDK : No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

I've downloaded the latest version of the C# SDK - using Windows 7, VS 2010 and .NET 4.

I've got the website running on my local IIS 7.

I have a Facebook developer account etc. and am trying to get the CSASPNETFacebookApp sample working.

When I access my app. I get the Facebook logon and border.

I logon and then get:

> No connection could be made because
>   the target machine actively refused it
>   66.220.146.50:443

nslookup 66.220.147.38

shows

Name:    api-read-12-04-snc4.facebook.com
Address:  66.220.147.38

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm getting same error. How did you solved it (what was the problem)? thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you set the URL's correctly in the application settings page on Facebook?
Is the "Site URL" set to http://localhost:xxxx  for example?

Comment: I have set the URL's up. Instead of using localhost, I use a "dummy" address e.g. www.testfb.co.nz and then in my hosts file, I map this to 127.0.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

I get this all the time from the Graph API.  I think it's Facebook's fault.  I think because they have too many connections it sometimes won't query your data and give you results back.  In my experience, I do all my Graph requests in a loop that repeats (max of 4 times) when that error occurs.  ususally the second or third time it works.  Some times it just doesn't.  IDK

Try the loop and see if that works